# Как вставить элементы массива в массив?

Tags: javascript

Как вставить элементы массива в массив?

Я пытаюсь так но не получается:

```
var t = "'-pro', 'co', 'optimize', 't2'";

[eval(t), output, input]
```

Comment: `eval` выполняет [оператор запятая](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F), возвращает последний элемент. Нужно обязательно строку такого формата вставить?

Comment: `eval` делает не то, что вы думаете. Он не вставляет кусок кода в то место, где `eval` написан, а запускает код, записанный в строке `t` отдельно от всего, вычисляет записанное там выражение и возвращает его результат как результат вызова функции. Как это выражение вычисляется, выше Other рассказал

Comment: @andreymal  Ооо Вы меня поняли, а возможно ли это реализовать в JS?

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов во-первых, скорее всего нет (хотя зависит от конкретной задачи, которую вы решаете), во-вторых, всё-таки зачем?

Comment: `[...eval(\`[${t}]\`), output, input]`

Comment: @Grundy, зачем учите плохому? :)

Comment: @Other, если вход именно такая строка, то почему нет? :)

Comment: @Other суровые бесчувственные люди, которые просто без церемоний отвечают на поставленный вопрос и не задумываются о последствиях)

Comment: @Grundy, а как же святой принцип: "Всегда считай что на входе самые злостные данные"?

Comment: @andreymal, конечно, он же бот.

Comment: @Other, его придумали тру́сы :)

Comment: @Grundy Оо Спасибо!  Это действительно работает. Мне нужно это для специфического ввода данных.

Comment: @Grundy, как же, этот принцип меня не раз спасал :)

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов, в любом случае проверяйте что пришло. И да - spread довольно новый, так что совместимость смотрите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одинарные кавычки обработать по месту напильником.

```js
var output = "out";
var input = "in";
var t = "'-pro', 'co', 'optimize', 't2'";
var arr = t.split(", ");
arr.push(output);
arr.push(input);
console.log(arr);
// извращение без метода push
var arr1 = eval("[" + t + ", '" + output + "', '" + input + "']");
console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: Спасибо, но нужно без метода push. То есть пуш вставляет данные в массив, а нужно вставить именно элемент массива в массив. Грубо говоря есть массив и нужно в него добавить наверное строку в виде массива, которую нужно как-то преобразовать в объект - как-то так.

Comment: Что за извращение? `Array#concat` есть :)

Comment: Кавычки можно напильником обрезать: `arr.map(e => e.replace(/^['"]|['"]$/g, '');)`.